# How to limit ftp access to multiple places for one user

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I don't even know how to write the correct question since it is a little confusing to ask it. Here is the problem. User X would like FTP access to /user/x folder and to /var/www/x folder. How can I manage to give the user access to both places without making 2 ftp accounts for each. Am using vsftpd on Ubuntu 11.04. He will use filezilla to login and wants to see the following structure or something similare to it:

```
/ <-- The root of the ftp directory  
usr/x <-- The user X  
www/x <-- The www folder for X
```

Is this possible all in one ftp access account?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks already got the answer. It was a simple mount option. For example in that case I did this inside the www/x folder:

`mkdir userx` (Which will be the /usr/x folder)
`mount --bind /usr/x userx`

And then gave the permissions needed for the user. This way the user got the structure like this:

```
/  
userx <-- Which is the /user/x folder)
```

and he can work on both places from a single FTP user.

After the permissions I then add this to the runtime so when the PC reboots it hold the binding of mount afterwards.