# Is it possible to edit vsftpd.conf giving ftp access to an user to only a few directories inside the server?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, account-restrictions

I want to know if a user can access multiple directories in a ftp server and no other directories. I want access to more than 1 directory. I know how to restrict access to a single directory by giving --
    chroot_local_user=YES

```
local_root=<accessible_directory>
```

There is a workaround described in the following url by using the mount command.
[How to limit ftp access to multiple places for one user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22022/how-to-limit-ftp-access-to-multiple-places-for-one-user)
Is there a better way to this?